# Error when I start React Application with "npm start"

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to start my ReactApp with `npm start` but I get this error.

[image]

This is my `2020-12-04T08_46_32_422Z-debug.log`.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v14.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle weather-app@0.1.0~prestart: weather-app@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle weather-app@0.1.0~start: weather-app@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle weather-app@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle weather-app@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Caín\reactProjects\WeatherApp\weather-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Caín\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Caín\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Caín\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Caín\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\Programas\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin
9 verbose lifecycle weather-app@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Caín\reactProjects\WeatherApp\weather-app
10 silly lifecycle weather-app@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle weather-app@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle weather-app@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: weather-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid weather-app@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Caín\reactProjects\WeatherApp\weather-app
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.4.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error weather-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the weather-app@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Commands I tried:

`npm install --save-dev cross-env`

`npm install`

`npm run build`

`npm cache clean --force`

`npm  run build -prod`

`node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod`

Anyone knows how to help me? And please, if you need more information, just let me know!
A lot of thanks!!

EDIT1: At the request of a very friendly user, I show you my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "weather-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```

*I'm writing more text because I can't send the post, hahaha, well, a greeting from Barcelona, have a great Friday!*

Comment: Have you tried using `npm i react-scripts -D`? Then running npm start.

Comment: Can you post your package.json?

Comment: @RobBailey Lool, thanks man!!! Now it works!!! You are the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: `npm i react-scripts -D`.

Comment: Hi Alex. Could you please add an explanation to all your answers even if it is only a brief one. Some tips here about what to write: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.